# How do I print the index of which an element has been found after linear search? Java

Tags: java

I am making a program in which a linear search is used to iterate through an array of 100 randomly generated numbers which are less than 10000.

The user enters a startNumber, midNumber and endNumber and the linear search will iterate through the array and tell the user at which index the elements have been found

I have implemented the linear search and everything seems to be working fine but it seems that I cannot print out the index of elements when found after linear search has been implemented.

I have provided code, input and output:

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // generating n, 0 < n < 10000 and 0 < length < 100
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] arr = new int[100];
    for (int z = 0; z < arr.length; z++) {
      arr[z] = rand.nextInt(10000);

    }
    // sorting 
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    int startNum = scanner.nextInt();
    int midNum = scanner.nextInt();
    int endNum = scanner.nextInt();

    // linear search
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (startNum == arr[i]) {
            System.out.println("Found");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
            
        }
        // where I want to print out the final message such as "startNum found at i"
    }
}
```

}

**Input:**
254
1467
8185

**Output:**

Found
Not Found
Not Found
Not Found
Not Found
Not Found
Not Found
No
...(keeps printing not found?)

I just want to keep this simple , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can create `boolean` variables for each of these three numbers to track if they are found or not. Wherever they are found, print their index and change the value of the corresponding `boolean` variable to `true`.
2. After the loop terminates, check the value of these `boolean` variables and print the **Not Found** message if their value has not changed to `true`.

**Code:**

```
boolean startNumFound = false, midNumFound = false, endNumFound = false;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (startNum == arr[i]) {
        System.out.println(startNum + " was found at index, " + i);
        startNumFound = true;
    } else if (midNum == arr[i]) {
        System.out.println(midNum + " was found at index, " + i);
        midNumFound = true;
    } else if (endNum == arr[i]) {
        System.out.println(endNum + " was found at index, " + i);
        endNumFound = true;
    }
}
if (!startNumFound) {
    System.out.println(startNum + " was not found");
}
if (!midNumFound) {
    System.out.println(midNum + " was not found");
}
if (!endNumFound) {
    System.out.println(endNum + " was not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the result outside of loop, then simply define another variable with value of `-1` because indexes start with zero then store the index of founded element inside it and if nothing found then value will be `-1` which means not found:

```
// linear search
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (startNum == arr[i]) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (index != -1) {
    System.out.print(startNum + " Found at index: " + index);
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Found");
}
```